TextInput bug in react native on web, Only one character being entered before losing focus
The issue im having is when I have a textInput I can only type in one character and then TextInput loses focus.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const Blank = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    const MyTable = () => {
        //functions
        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={(input) => setText(input)} />
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.screenView}>
            <MyTable />
        </View>
    );
}

I have tried moving the TextInput directly into the "Blank"s return block which does fix the issue but I have certain functions that need to be performed in the MyTable function. Is there any way to make this work without the use of useEffect since my actually project is fairly large and i dont want a bunch of unnecessary code in my useEffect when it could be inside MyTable

You can create the function outside your mainfunction
const Blank = ({ navigation, route }) => {
const [text, setText] = useState("");

return (
    <View style={styles.screenView}>
        <MyTable text={text} setText={setText}/>
    </View>
)}

const MyTable = ({ text, setText }) => {
return (
    <View>
        <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={(input) => setText(input)} />
    </View>
)}


Thanks so much, never thought to try that
